# cassandra pelops exception "socket write error" once some data is inserted in batch in cassandra java

Tags: java, cassandra, pelops

"org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error"

Getting this error after some batches are processed(i.e some data is inserted into the cassandra)
m using pelops client for casssandra
consistency level is ONE

Thanks,
samarth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the Cassandra log for errors?